# Dateparser custom current date time consideration config update

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime, dateparser

```
import dateparser
print(dateparser.parse("1 week"))
print(dateparser.parse("1 month"))
print(dateparser.parse("6 months"))
print(dateparser.parse("1 year"))
```

The above code lines return the below output:

```
2022-01-27 11:30:50.229535
2022-01-03 11:30:50.231393
2021-08-03 11:30:50.232393
2021-02-03 11:30:50.232938
```

Essentially they consider the current timestamp and return prev one week or prev one moth or prev 6 months or prev one year  date time. What if I want date parser to consider a custom timestamp and based on that return the prev one week or prev one moth or prev 6 months or prev one year  date time?? For Example: For the same above code, I want the below output because I want date parser to consider the start date as 2021-06-13 11:30:50.229535

```
2022-06-06 11:30:50.229535
2022-05-14 11:30:50.231393
2021-01-13 11:30:50.232393
2020-06-13 11:30:50.232938
```

how to go about configuring this start date?

Answer (score 0):

You can define that in the [settings dict](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dateparser.html#dateparser.conf.Settings), via the `RELATIVE_BASE` key.

From the [docs](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html):

> RELATIVE_BASE: allows setting the base datetime to use for interpreting partial or relative date strings. Defaults to the current date and time.

Ex:

```
from datetime import datetime
import dateparser

settings={'RELATIVE_BASE': datetime.fromisoformat("2021-06-13 11:30:50.229535")}

print(dateparser.parse("1 week", settings=settings))
print(dateparser.parse("1 month", settings=settings))
print(dateparser.parse("6 months", settings=settings))
print(dateparser.parse("1 year", settings=settings))
# 2021-06-06 11:30:50.229535
# 2021-05-13 11:30:50.229535
# 2020-12-13 11:30:50.229535
# 2020-06-13 11:30:50.229535
```